# Disable and enable search when button is not an INPUT using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, disabled-input

I have seen examples of this being done where the button is an INPUT but I can't seem to make it work with this example below where the Input[type=button] is replaced with a Span/Icon. I can't post all my code here, but I hope this is enough to receive help.

I want to disable the span until a user clicks into the text field:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.header-search-btn').prop('disabled', true);
    $('input[type="text"].header-search').keyup(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            $('.header-search-btn').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.fa-arrow-right::before {
    content: "\25B6";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="search" class="header-search" placeholder="Search" id="searchInput">
<div class="header-search-btn">
    <span class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true" id="submitBtn"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.header-search-btn').prop('disabled'` You are adding a disabled attribute to a `div`, that attribute cannot be added to a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `disabled` property on divs.

But you could simply show / hide the arrow.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.header-search-btn').hide();
  $('input[type="text"].header-search').keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
      $('.header-search-btn').show();
    } else {
      $('.header-search-btn').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.fa-arrow-right::before {
  content: "\25B6";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="search" class="header-search" placeholder="Search" id="searchInput">
<div class="header-search-btn"> <span class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true" id="submitBtn"></span> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to the `span` hidden UNTIL the user clicks into the `input` field, then this will do it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.header-search-btn').hide();
    $('input[type="text"].header-search').on("click", function() {

            $('.header-search-btn').show();
    });
});
```

```css
.fa-arrow-right::before {
    content: "\25B6";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="search" class="header-search" placeholder="Search" id="searchInput">
<div class="header-search-btn">
    <span class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true" id="submitBtn"></span>
</div>
```